# How can I do an atomic write/append in C#, or how do I get files opened with the FILE_APPEND_DATA flag?

Tags: c#, .net, append, atomic

Under most Unixes and Posix conforming operating systems performing an open() operating system call with the O_APPEND indicates to the OS that writes are to be atomic append and write operations. With this behavior,for local filesystems when you do a write, you know it get appended to the end of the file.

The Windows operating systems support the same functionality by passing `FILE_APPEND_DATA` in the appropriate parameter to the Win32 CreateFile() system call.

references:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+createfile
or: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx

http://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint
or: http://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint
```

My problem is this, I cannot determine how to get this behavior under C# using the Net Framework
Libraries, is there a way to get such behavior using the Net Framework?
I do not believe using FileMode.Append gives such behavior, by the way.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use one of the overloads of the `FileStream` constructor:

```
new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileSystemRights.AppendData,
            FileShare.Write, 4096, FileOptions.None)
```

`FileSystemRights.AppendData` corresponds with `FILE_APPEND_DATA`

FileStream seems to insist on buffering, so make sure the buffer is large enough for each
write and call `Flush()` after each write.

Tiny example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(DoIt);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(DoIt);
        t1.Start("a");
        t2.Start("b");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void DoIt(object p) {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileSystemRights.AppendData,
            FileShare.Write, 4096, FileOptions.None)) {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                    writer.WriteLine("{0}: {1:D3} {2:o} hello", p, i, DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the same as using the `File.AppendText` API?

Comment: The last parameter of the FileStream constructor, 'bufferSize', or 4096 in this example will be an upper bound on the length of an atomic write.

Comment: Apparently FileSystemRights is not in dotnetstandard 2.0.

Comment: Does it matter if you use FileMode.Append or FileMode.Open? Open will not create the file if it does not exist

Comment: @silvalli You can use [FileSystemAclExtensions.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions.create?view=net-6.0#system-io-filesystemaclextensions-create(system-io-fileinfo-system-io-filemode-system-security-accesscontrol-filesystemrights-system-io-fileshare-system-int32-system-io-fileoptions-system-security-accesscontrol-filesecurity)) in .NET Core 3+

Answer (score 1):

You can call [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateFile.html) with the required parameters and pass the resulting handle to one of the [FileStream Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream.aspx) which takes SafeFileHandle as a parameter.

Answer (score -3):

Why can't you use

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\somefile.txt", "some content");
```

? That's a thread-safe/"atomic" call as well.

Comment: This unfortunatly doesn't give the process-wise atomic operation i'm looking for.

Comment: Throws an IOException with File is being used by another process when multiple threads access the file.