# One process writes to file, I open it manualy (readonly) , I got exception "The process cannot access the file ..."?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, multiprocessing, streamwriter

I'm trying to allow just one process be able to write to a file and other processes could only read it , so I tried to open the file by:

`sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)`);

and then there is a write loop:

```
while(true)
{   
//some code
    sw.Write(message);
}

sw.close();
```

while this process writes to the file, I tried to open it manually I recive a message to open the file in readonly mode , when I press "readonly" button the writer process throws exception "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file."

how I could fix it ?

Comment: I don't believe you can make this work, and will need to consider different approaches, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507770/write-to-a-file-from-multiple-threads-asynchronously-c-sharp

Comment: follow up with previous comment check this article too [multiple process write file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690537/multi-processes-readwrite-one-file)

Comment: I have tried your code and don't see any issues if you are just wanting to monitor the file try opening it with baretail https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "open it manually"?

Comment: I tried to open it by myself, not by another code , the OS release the lock for specific time and then the writer process acquire it again and continue to work normaly

Comment: So, if the lock is temporary, catch the exception and perform some number of retries perhaps with a delay between each retry.